# Data loss due to simultaneous transmission in ZigBee

Tags: communication, zigbee

I'm designing a multi-agent robotic application, where robots communicate through [ZigBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZigBee) modules. If two (or more) robots send their data simultaneously (at the same time) will it cause data loss at the receiver?

Consider multiple senders and one receiver (where senders send data simultenously and receiver receives them and perform certain tasks).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a full ZigBee stack (something like [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee), Freescale, etc.), it should handle checking for a clear channel before sending as well as resending data if there is failure. Our networks have hundreds of ZigBee nodes and we very, very rarely see any data loss.